# baseline seems to change automatically

Tags: spacing, xetex, debugging

I don't have a MWE, since this appeared on the bottom of page 12 of a document I'm working on (by surprise).  I'm just wondering if anyone will recognize what's going on.  It looks to me as though the inter-line spacing changes a lot, without any request from me that that should happen:

> [image]

This behavior wasn't requested and if possible I'd  like to make sure it doesn't occur.  I printed out `\baselineskip` and `\baselinestretch` and they appear to be the same in both paragraphs.

I'd welcome relevant debugging tips.  Note that a few paragraphs later the spacing in the document is back to normal.

The source code for this region (and a bit more) is:

```
conversation is actually foundational for meaning.  It looks as though
Ogden and Richards have already been all over this point, and so I'll
cede the floor to
them.\footnote{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_reference}}

\paragraph{A fundamental dilemma}
Quote \ref{myq:71} puts forth the quote, which is not due to
\citet{serres1982parasite} (as it might appear) but which is actually
from \citet{clarke1999constructing} -- which I'm trying to track down.
\begin{quote}
With this recognition the phatic function becomes the constitutive
occasion for all communication, which can thus no longer be
conceptualized in the absence of difference and delay, resistance,
static, and noise.\footnote{Quoted it \cite{siegert2007cacography}.}
\end{quote}
Something very similar to this is what interested me in phatics in my
```

Comment: i'd take a look at the input.  the last paragraph looks like it may be wrapped in an environment that could possibly change the `\baselineskip` or even the font size (which gets only partly reset before the end of the environment).  if an environment ends in horizontal mode (without a `\par`) the baselines don't get reset.

Comment: How is the typesetting for "A fundamental dilemma" defined?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added the source code for this region.  Nothing too fancy.  Perhaps the issue is that there's a quote immediately after the page break?

Comment: You don't show the source through the end of the paragraph, though, so we don't know what is going on then.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, your comment showed the way to resolve it.  I'm pretty amazed that this is the first time I've encountered this issue... (or at least this the first time I've been *aware* of encountering the issue!)

Comment: Apparently your document has some redefinition of `quote`; can you show it?

Comment: as egreg hints, this looks like a bug in the definition of `quote` used but impossible to debug unseen code.

Comment: I put another question with an MWE [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313588/whats-wrong-with-my-quote-environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, following up on Barbara Beeton's comment -- it's just a matter of introducing white space between the standard text and the `\begin{quote}` and `\end{quote}`.

```
conversation is actually foundational for meaning.  It looks as though
Ogden and Richards have already been all over this point, and so I'll
cede the floor to them.\footnote{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_reference}}

\paragraph{A fundamental dilemma}
Quote \ref{myq:71} puts forth the quote, which is not due to
\citet{serres1982parasite} (as it might appear) but which is actually
from \citet{clarke1999constructing} -- which I'm trying to track down.

\begin{quote}
With this recognition the phatic function becomes the constitutive
occasion for all communication, which can thus no longer be
conceptualized in the absence of difference and delay, resistance,
static, and noise.\footnote{Quoted it \cite{siegert2007cacography}.}
\end{quote}

Something very similar to this is what interested me in phatics in my
```

Comment: indeed.  this is a problem that shows up when a math display (with no `\par` separation from the preceding text) is "smallified" -- the baselines above are shrunk.  of course, you *don't want* a paragraph break there; it could lead to a page break (verboten in good style), and it always fouls up the pre-display spacing.  so it's a real problem.  still figuring out the "best" approach to a solution ... after many years.

Comment: @barbarabeeton By why isn't it the font size at the end of the paragraph which matters?

Comment: @cfr -- ordinarily a math display is *part* of a paragraph.  when the display is made smaller by changing the font, it is enclosed in a group, and to complete the "smaller" material, the group is ended by an implicit paragraph break, which is enough to keep the display consistent, but is overridden so that text that follows without an explicit paragraph break (either by `\par` or a blank line) won't be indented.  but it's enough to foul up the baselines in the text preceding the display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. That's what I guessed: that the trivial list must add an implicit paragraph break somehow.

Comment: it's impossible really to comment without seeing the code which you have not shown in the question or answer. You should never need a blank line before quote, are you using the definition from the standard packages or a custom definition?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle now that I understand the issue I can convert the question into a MWE.  I'll do that shortly.