# what's wrong with my (smaller) quote environment?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, quoting

In [baseline seems to change automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313427/baseline-seems-to-change-automatically) I noticed that the baseline in some pieces of text was changing without an obvious request from me to make it change.  Barbara Beeton helped me figure out what the basic issue was, and other commenters correctly guessed that I'd modified the `quote` environment.  Accordingly I can now turn the question into a MWE.  I'm certainly curious to understand the underlying issue.

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{5in}{5in}
\settrimmedsize{5in}{5in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{3in}{3in}{*}
\setlrmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{1.5\onelineskip}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller\em}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

Things are looking fine so far... xxxxxxxxx xxxx xx x x x x
xxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxx xxxxxxxx x xxxx.

A bit squeezed in this paragraph...  xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xx x x x
x xxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx
%% - remove these comments to fix spacing (1/2)
\begin{quote}
This is a quote.  y yyyyyyyyyy yyy yyy yyy yyyy yyyyyyyyyy yyyy yy y y
y y yyyyyyyyyyyy y yyyy
\end{quote}
%% - remove these comments to fix spacing (2/2)
This is another paragraph, things are fine again.  xxx xxx xxxx xxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xx x x x x xxxxxxxxxxxx x
xxxx

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note the `This is another paragraph` shows why the suggested workaround of adding a blank line would be wrong. latex carefully distinguishes the case you have with a mid-paragraph quote and the following text not indented from a between-paragraph quote where the following text is indented. If you add a blank line before the quote it forces the between-para interpretation and would cause the text after the quote to indent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tokens `\smaller\em` are added *before* `quote` starts a new paragraph, so the new baseline skip is applied also the not yet ended paragraph.

Do, instead,

```
\appto\quote{\smaller\em}
```

that will execute `\smaller` at the beginning of the quote.

[image]

Comment: I found `\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\smaller\em}` adding a `\par` seems to also work.  Is one better than the other?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The `\appto` way is better, because does the settings at the last moment, after all settings for `quote` are done.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes adding `\par` is wrong for same reason ading a blank line before the environment is wrong (see the comment I added under the question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for that note.  I guess that means that stuff like `\parskip` would also erroneously come into play.